# Как указать правильный путь к гит для пуша?

Tags: java, android, git, github, gitlab

Я скачал пример гугла, внес свои изменения и теперь хочу залить его себе на репазиторий `gitlab`,

сделал эти команды

> cd existing_folder
>
> git init
>
> git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/rosental/Mobile.git
>
> git add .

Потом зашел в студию сделал коммит, он прошел,  но при пуше получаю такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понимаю, то в папке проекта где то уже инициализирован файл гита, так как в ошибке видно, что он пытается его запушить на адрес репозитория гугла, а не на мой...

Как это можно починить? Где это указывается?

Comment: `git remote set-url` ?

Comment: @alexolut А как эту команду правильно использовать?

Comment: ??? https://www.dropbox.com/s/2a7w5yr3mb3wrbd/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%281%29.png?dl=0

Comment: @ЮрийСПб та не... Мне на gitlab надо... Я там добавил описание в вопрос

Comment: 403? Похоже, гитлаб не узнаёт вас в гриме.

Comment: @Кнопкатык там github написано. нету доступа к нему. человеку нужно залить в свой репозиторий на gitlab. значит нужно поменять ссылку на свой репозиторий, а потом заливать.

Comment: @SkiesX Да, скриншот я недостаточно рассмотрел, вы правы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выполните эту команду:

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/rosental/Mobile.git
```

А потом, для отправки все на сервер:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Да это то, что нужно было... А можете еще пожалуйста обьяснить как это сработало? В чем была проблема?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko когда Вы скачали проект, то в конфигах Git к этому проекту был указан другой репозиторий, на Github (ссылку на него можно увидеть на скрине что Вы кидали, справа сверху в уведомлениях). Для того чтобы сделать `push` в свой репозиторий (на gitlab) нужно поменять ссылку. Команда `git remote add origin` устанавливает путь к репозиторию тогда когда его нет. Но у путь к репозиторию уже стоял (на github), значит его нужно заменить (на gitlab), команда `git remote set-url origin` как раз это делает, изменяет путь в конфигурации git к проекту.

Comment: Все ясно стало сразу)) Спасибо!